# How do I properly make a Django QuerySet where some field has values in a list?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-database

I have a bunch of Widget objects.

Now each widget has a string property called 'foo'. And I need to be able to query for Widgets that have 'foo' set to 'red', 'orange', 'green' or any arbitrary color, and include only Widgets that have that appropriate 'foo' property. Also, these colors are coming from user input, so I can't trust them. I would rather not load all the results and then filter them, but rather do this in SQL.

However… I only see ways to join clauses with "AND", never "OR". And "in" is garbage ('in' only works on numerical IDs, or a sub-queryset, which reduces to the same problem!). I tried some other things, but they didn’t seem to work.

Basically, I’m asking how to express this as a key of `filterQuery` below.

```
myNiceWidgets = Widget.objects.filter(**filterQuery).orderBy(...)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `OR`, look into django's `Q` objects.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
Widget.objects.filter(Q(foo='red') | Q(foo='green'), **filterQuery)
```

It won't work as a key of `filterQuery` as the Q object must be a positional argument.

> Lookup functions can mix the use of Q objects and keyword arguments.
>   All arguments provided to a lookup function (be they keyword arguments
>   or Q objects) are "AND"ed together. However, if a Q object is
>   provided, it must precede the definition of any keyword arguments. For
>   example:

Comment: Thanks. Weird I didn’t bump into this in the Django docs. Appreciate it, Yuji.

Answer (score 2):

This:

> 'in' only works on numerical IDs, or a sub-queryset

is nonsense. `in` is fine with a list of names:

```
Widget.objects.filter(foo__in=['red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'])
```

Comment: This may be – the field in question was actually a foreign key, which is why it was trying to turn everything into `int`s.

Comment: @AlanH if you want to query a *field* on on that target table, you'd use double underscore syntax `Widget.objects.filter(foo__color__in=['red', 'orange'])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

I also ended doing a few sub-queries in a list comprehension, then grabbing those IDs and using `in`. It was (hopefully) worthwhile because I used the intermediate objects again later in the request.

Comment: … but I should have done this in one query. And as Daniel says, probably an `__in` query would do the trick.